# React Date Picker is not updated after typing manually

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datepicker

When I do not pick the date from the window and type it manually, it sets the correct date but it will not update the input field according to the picked date.

```
        <DateInput
            onChange={onChange}
            selected={date}
        >

const onChange = useCallback(date) => {
        console.log(date)
        setDate(date);
    }, [props.onChange, setDate])
```

[image]

[image]

Here are the photos of how I picked the date and what shows up. I am very new to React sorry. How can I update the value of the input field after. Thanks